# What does `kill -0` do?

Tags: command-line, scripts

I am having trouble understanding shell script below. Specifically, what is `Kill -0` (zero)

```bsh
while kill -0 ${docker_pid} 2>/dev/null
do
   #do something here
done
```

All the documentation for kill signals I have found starts documenting from 1...31

```bsh
#ifndef _POSIX_SOURCE
#include <machine/trap.h>   /* codes for SIGILL, SIGFPE */
#endif /* _POSIX_SOURCE */

#define SIGHUP  1   /* hangup */
#define SIGINT  2   /* interrupt */
#define SIGQUIT 3   /* quit */
#define SIGILL  4   /* illegal instruction (not reset when caught) */
#ifndef _POSIX_SOURCE
#define SIGTRAP 5   /* trace trap (not reset when caught) */
#endif
... signal.h continues ....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kill -0 <pid>` just gives a return value 0 if the process exists, and 1 if it doesn't.

Comment: thanks for answering. any tutorial on this or reference?

Comment: `kill -0 1963 | echo` is returning a blank line. 1963 is pid for my `/bin/bash`. what am i doing wrong

Comment: `kill -0 1234; echo $?` is the right syntax. $? is the return value of the last executed command. This works for ll commands.

Comment: This is very useful in scripts, especially `if kill -0 $PID; then...fi` type of command or `while kill -0 $PID`  to see if particular process is running ans do something about it. Some commands create `.pid` file to advertise their own PID, and in case it may not have removed the file, `kill -0` can verify if command actually exited or not.

Comment: @DrDeo there's reference to it in this [linux.org thread under "The Zero Signal"](https://www.linux.org/threads/kill-signals-and-commands-revised.11625/). On Kubuntu 18.04 my `/bin/kill` [kill from procps-ng 3.3.12] doesn't handle SIGT but bash has a built-in kill that does. Even so `kill -l 0` returns `T` but `kill -l` doesn't list it as a usable signal. The installed `/bin/kill` doesn't handle `SIGT` nor `0`.